# How to resize iAd BannerView in iOS7

Tags: ios, resize, iad

iOS7, Xcode5

I add an iAd into my app, this app is a master-detail app running on iPad.

I drag the Ad BannerView into the detail view in storyboard, then write some codes. 
Followed this lesson: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fP2ijcXbCz4

Codes:

```
-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

It works well except that the size of the banner.

In portrait(detail width 768), the banner's width is fit(length 768), but in landscape(detail width 703), the banner's width is still 768, so some contents of the iAd is missing.

I add some constraints to the Ad BannerView, but it seems they don't work at all.

I also try this:

```
[self.ad setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

It still does't change the size in landscape.

So, what can I do to fit the Ad BannerView's size in both portrait and landscape?
Thanks a lot!!